# Chi Distribution Problems

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't really understand how to solve these...could anyone help me out?

1)How to find the expected value of χ2(9) ?

2)We have a point A(x,y,z) in a 3 dimensional space. Each of the coordinates is independent and has a normal distribution. Find the probability that the distance from the origin to this point is no more than 1.5 .

Comment: It would be nice if you would show some work ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the expected value with $k$ dof:
\begin{align*}
E(X) & = \int_0^\infty x \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} x^{k/2 - 1} e^{-x/2}\, dx \\
& = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{k/2} e^{-x/2}\, dx \\
&  = \frac{2}{\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty u^{k/2} e^{-u}\, du \qquad (u := x/2)\\
&  = \frac{2}{\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty u^{(k/2+1) - 1} e^{-u}\, du \\
&  = \frac{2}{\Gamma(k/2)}\Gamma(k/2 + 1) \qquad \text{(defn. Gamma function)}\\
&  = \frac{2}{\Gamma(k/2)}\frac{k}{2}\Gamma(k/2) \qquad (\Gamma(n+1) = n\Gamma(n))\\
&  = k
\end{align*}

I'm assuming each coordinate $X, Y, Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, independent.  Let $D = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}$ be the distance from the origin, so $D^2 \sim \chi^2(3)$.  We want $P(D \leq 3/2) = P(D^2 \leq 9/4)$:
\begin{align*}
P(D^2 < 9/4) & = \int_0^{9/4} \frac{1}{2^{3/2}\Gamma(3/2)} x^{3/2 - 1} e^{-x/2}\, dx \\
& =  \frac{1}{2\Gamma(3/2)}\int_0^{9/4}  \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{1/2} e^{-x/2}\, dx \\
& =  \frac{1}{\Gamma(3/2)}\int_0^{9/8}  u^{1/2} e^{-u}\, du \qquad (u := x/2)\\
& =  \frac{1}{\Gamma(3/2)}\int_0^{9/8}  u^{3/2 - 1} e^{-u}\, du \\
& =  \frac{\gamma(3/2, 9/8)}{\Gamma(3/2)} \qquad \text{(defn. lower incomplete Gamma function)} \\
& \approx. 0.4778
\end{align*}